# Ubuntu Server in VMWare terminal stops updating

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I'm running an Ubuntu Server 12.10 in VMWare Fusion 5, no Xwin/GUI, just the bare terminal. I run top in that so I can keep an eye on what's loading the server, and after about 10-15 minutes, the terminal stops updating. If I send focus to it and press any key, it'll continue updating again for a while. It's as if there was a screen saver of sorts. Googling this behaviour, all I can find is sleeping/suspending/hibernating Ubuntu machines from the terminal... not what I need to know.

Does anyone know how to disable this "screen saver" function?

Thanks

- Balt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seriously doubt this is a terminal screensaver issue.

I had once a similar issue, where the terminal screen got blank after a few minutes. The solution was to upgrade the VMware host.

Anyway, if this really is an input issue causing the screen to go blank and freezing VMware from receiving updates from the client, try the following command to disable the terminal blank screen:

```
setterm -blank 0
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: @Balthasar good to know your issue was easier to solve then mine!